# Ionic 2 twitter embedded timeline issue

Tags: typescript, iframe, twitter, ionic2

Im trying to use a twitter embedded time line in my ionic 2 app.
So far i have the code shown  below, however after the user leaves the view the time line disappears? Is there something im missing here?

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
   <button ion-button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
    <ion-title>Social Media</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding> 
  <a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/amyawards2017" data-widget-id="837781109337436160">#amyawards2017 Tweets</a>
  <!--<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>-->
</ion-content>




export class SocialMediaPage{
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,private toastCtrl: ToastController,
  private alertCtrl: AlertController,
  public twitter: TwitterService) {

  }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
            !function(d,s,id){
                var js: any,
                    fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                    p='https';
                if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                    js=d.createElement(s);
                    js.id=id;
                    js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
                }
            }
            (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    }



}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ngAfterViewInit with this one.

```
!function(d,s,id){
            var js: any,
                fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p='https';
                js=d.createElement(s);
                js.id=id;
                js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
        (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

I do not know if it works for you but for my application it worked.
I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

replace ngAfterViewInit with ionViewDidEnter e.g.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    !function(d,s,id){
        ...
    }
    (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
}
```

ngAfterViewInit is only called when the view is initialised, whereas ionViewDidEnter is called every time the view is navigated to (from another view)

note that because of this if you switch to different content within the same page you will still get this error (e.g. if you are using an [ionic segment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/) on the page). If this is the case you will need to find or setup a suitable event for your use, for example with ion-segments:

HTML:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="model" (ionChange)="segmentChanged()">
```

TS:

```
updateTwitter() {
    !function(d,s,id){
        ...
    }
    (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
}
segmentChanged() {
    this.updateTwitter();
}
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.updateTwitter();
}
```